# Bleed lines in Pixelmator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, layers, file-format, pixelmator

I designed a label for printing in Pixelmator. If the printers don’t have Pixelmator they can’t see my layers... How do I save it that someone using AI can open it?

Comment: Please read [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts). If you do this, you will be able to comment on answers to your own post and accept an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try saving as a PDF or PSD file.

See the below link for the types of files you can save as.

https://www.pixelmator.com/tutorials/contents/export-and-share-images/

Comment: thank you, i've tried this but when i send it, it still doesn't save all the layers separately and when they open it, it is still an image.

Comment: @Shantelle if saving as either of those files doesn't work then I would suggest contacting the developer to see what they say. Another option is to delete everything that isn't part of "layer 1" then save. Then delete everything that isn't part of "layer 2", then save, etc. Why does your printer need to see the layers? Is this for printing shirts?